# How to get single keystroke in D2  (Phobos)?

Tags: input, keyboard, d, phobos

Is there a simple, cross-platform way to get a single keystroke in D2 using Phobos?

For instance, a "Press any key to continue..." prompt, or a Brainfuck interpreter.

All the methods I've tried require an Enter keypress before passing the input (getchar(), for instance).

Comment: Please be more specific.  D1 or D2?  Phobos or Tango?

Comment: In C, the `getch` function from the non-standard `conio.h` header does what you want. From what I can tell, though, it's not in D's `std.c.*` however. I'll keep looking.

Comment: This thread has some relevant information: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/undefined_identifier_getch_23132.html

Comment: I just do `Press ENTER to continue...` and get it over with. :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done some research on the matter, and I've found that, while the Phobos library under D 1.0 had exactly what you need in the form of `std.c.stdio.getch()`, D 2.0 lacks this function. None of the other standard input functions in Phobos appear to have the behavior you want.

As I understand it, this is because the desired behavior (that is, getting a single character without the need for an Enter keypress) is rather nonstandard and has to be implemented in relatively ugly, platform-specific ways. (In its initial form, the function `getch` existed in C's [`<conio.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h), a DOS-specific header that has become somewhat of a de facto cross-platform standard despite not being part of the standard C library.) Evidently the maintainers of the Phobos runtime library decided to strip out this particular bit of backwards-compatible functionality in the name of a cleaner library, but at the expense of this functionality.

#### Manual declaration

[Reportedly](http://www.digitalmars.com/pnews/read.php?server=news.digitalmars.com&group=digitalmars.D.learn&artnum=23139), you can get around this missing function declaration by adding this to your source file:

```
extern (C) int getch();
```

However, I have found that this produces a linker error, suggesting that the function was removed from the runtime library entirely, rather than merely having its declaration removed from `std.c.stdio`. It's certainly worth a try—it might happen to work on your system and compiler, I really don't know.

**Edit 2:** This actually seems to work on Windows; it failed for me on the Linux side. It appears that DMD under Windows first links to the Phobos/D runtime (phobos.lib), then the C runtime (snn.lib); however, on Linux, DMD links to one runtime library that supplies both parts. This difference appears to cause linkage to undeclared functions (`getch` among them) to only work on Windows. If Windows is the only platform you're concerned with, this solution is probably suitable. If you need more cross-platform compatibility, read on.

#### ncurses

Another possibility is to use the `ncurses` library. It implements a [`getch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) function that will definitely do what you want—provided that you're cool with finding D bindings for the library or just using the C interface. Be aware that it requires a smidgen more setup than just calling the function you want; [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905060/non-blocking-getch-ncurses) has more information on the matter.

#### D 1.0

Now, for some considerably uglier solutions. Using D 1.0 would allow you to find what you need in the Phobos standard library—but this obviously entails using the older, crustier version of the language and I personally do not find the lack of one console IO function in the standard library to be justification for using the old version of D.

I believe that Tango also lost its `getch` declaration (under `tango.stdc.stdio`) over the switch to D 2.0, but my knowledge of Tango is extremely limited, so I may be wrong.

#### Write it yourself

If you're determined, you could just write your own `getch`. I wasn't able to find a cross-platform C implementation of `getch` using [Google Code Search](http://google.com/codesearch?as_q=getch), which leaves me pessimistic about the likelihood of a relatively simple, 10-line-or-so function implementation that could simply be adapted to D.

On the other hand, Walter Bright—you know, the guy who **designed** the D language—provides a D implementation of just this sort of function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99546/how-can-i-grab-single-key-hit-in-d-programming-language-tango/261583#261583). However, even this appears to be somewhat outdated, because one of the symbols, `cfmakeraw`, is undefined under the current version of the DMD2 compiler. However, it's really close to being a workable solution.

Comment: An addendum to the **Manual declaration** section: you might be able to add that function declaration to your code and then link to the Digital Mars C++ runtime library, which does define `getch`, as far as I'm aware. It probably won't work but it's worth mentioning. Another hacky solution for sure.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution that works with D2 on Windows:

```
import std.stdio : writefln;

extern(C) int kbhit();
extern(C) int getch();

void main()
{
    while(!kbhit())
    {
        // keep polling
        // might use Thread.Sleep here to avoid taxing the cpu.
    }

    writefln("Key hit was %s.", cast(char)getch());
}
```

It might even work with D1, but I haven't tried it out.

Here's a Linux version, modified from [Walter's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99546/how-can-i-grab-single-key-hit-in-d-programming-language-tango/261583#261583):

```
import std.stdio : writefln;
import std.c.stdio;
import std.c.linux.termios;

extern(C) void cfmakeraw(termios *termios_p);

void main() 
{
    termios  ostate;                 /* saved tty state */
    termios  nstate;                 /* values for editor mode */

       // Open stdin in raw mode
       /* Adjust output channel        */
    tcgetattr(1, &ostate);                       /* save old state */
    tcgetattr(1, &nstate);                       /* get base of new state */
    cfmakeraw(&nstate);
    tcsetattr(1, TCSADRAIN, &nstate);      /* set mode */

      // Read characters in raw mode
    writefln("The key hit is %s", cast(char)fgetc(stdin));

       // Close
    tcsetattr(1, TCSADRAIN, &ostate);       // return to original mode
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this on your system? On my system (compiler is DMD2), I get linker errors for `kbhit` and `getch`. I believe they were removed from the runtime library (see my answer for details)—or it could just be my version of the compiler, I can't speak for the Windows version.

Comment: @jgottula I'm using DMD 2.052. `kbhit` and `getch` are defined in snn.lib, which if I'm not mistaken is a compiler-specific library(?). GDC compiles this example as well.

Comment: I am on Linux x86_64 with DMD 2.049 (slightly behind the current 2.052). I'll look into whether anything like snn.lib exists on the Linux side. Perhaps this is a platform-specific library difference (wouldn't be surprising, given that `kbhit` and `getch` aren't *declared* in the standard library namespace).

Comment: snn.lib appears to be the Digital Mars C runtime library (see http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dmd-windows.html#linking). Unfortunately, the corresponding Linux page has nothing to say about which libraries are which.

Comment: Now I've found something telling: On the Windows side, the linker first links to phobos.lib (the D runtime), then links to snn.lib (the C runtime). But on Linux, everything appears to be contained in libphobos2.a (compare the linux/lib32 dir vs. the windows/lib dir in the DMD zip file). So it's apparent that things work fundamentally differently on different platforms, the result of which is that linking to C functions in the runtime library may not work all the time on Linux/Posix. :S

Comment: @jgottula: I've edited my post with a Linux solution to OP's problem, in case you haven't noticed. I've successfully compiled and used it on a recent Ubuntu installation.

Comment: That's neat! What did you change to alleviate the linker error I was getting with Walter's solution?

Comment: I've added the cfmakeraw prototype. I just did a quick google search and found its prototype on a wiki site, and modified it a little for use with D.