# Reading a single character from stdin in D

Tags: d, phobos

The [documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html) for `std.stdio` does not list a `read` function which could be used to get a single character from standard input, only `readln` to get a line. `std.file` has `read` function, but it needs a file name, which is not available for the standard input as far as I know.

How do I read a single character from `stdin`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get single keystroke in D2  (Phobos)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372646/how-to-get-single-keystroke-in-d2-phobos)

Comment: @CyberShadow Yup, didn't show up in the search. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options, depending on just what you need:

**If you just want a character for programming purposes but don't mind it being line buffered:**

- Use `rawRead` or `byChunk` to buffer a block of it (`stdin` is an instance of `std.stdio.File` so all methods from that http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html area available for it too) and read one item off that array at a time.
- Use the C function `fgetc` by `import core.stdc.stdio;` and using the C stdin instead of the D wrapper. They are both compatible with each other so reading from one won't mess up the buffering of the other.
- Use the `readf` function to grab one piece of data at a time.

All those options will work for your program, but you'll notice the user will still have to press enter before the program does anything because the underlying input stream is buffered to one complete line at a time. That can be changed too:

**If you want one key immediately, for things like interactive sessions with the user:**

- See CyberShadow's link in the comment
- Disable line buffering with an operating system call. It is `tcsetattr` on Posix and `SetConsoleMode` on Windows - search the web for details on how to disable line buffering in C, and the same code can be fairly easily translated to D. Also see the source to my terminal.d which does it: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/terminal.d#L1078
- Just use a library, like my terminal.d, which provides a struct to change the buffering mode for you and functions like `getch` and `kbhit`, similar to the old `conio.h` in the link. Here's an example file: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/book/chapter_12/07/input.d which shows a simple "press any key to continue" example.
- Use a more featured C library like `ncurses` from D. http://code.dlang.org/packages/ncurses If you've ever used it from C, it is pretty much the same.

Comment: >"and using the C stdin instead of the D wrapper" . Where is that C stdin defined in the D libs? in the same core.stdc.stdio?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what data type should be used for storing the character that we read in? byte/ubyte/int/uint/char? I had some issues with that. In C it is a straightforward "int c" that we use, even to read a character, since it needs to be able to signal EOF which is usually defined as -1 (IIRC). (Going by the K&R ANSI C Edition book, not sure if that has changed in recent C versions like C99 or higher).

Comment: The same as C - use int when using the C functions.

Comment: Thanks. Will check that option out. I was trying various combinations of the data types and the D vs. C libs, so might have not tried that combo you mention.